# Cloudera 5.6 spark memoryFraction settings

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

I have a CDH 5.6 cluster with 5.6 CDM (manager). I am not sure where I can set the memoryfaction settings of spark -

```
spark.storage.memoryFaction
spark.shuffle.memoryFaction
```

to try different settings and see performance of my sample application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either while creating the spark context:

```
  sparkContext = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Appname")
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFaction", "someval")
    new SparkContext(conf)
  }
```

or while doing a spark-submit, by adding:

```
 --conf spark.storage.memoryFaction=1
```